# how to decide categorical variables for prediction

Tags: predictive-modeling, categorical-data, forecast, forecasting

I have a dataset that contains weekly sales for stores and categories. It looks like this:

[image]

I would like to apply gradient boosting method to predict weekly sales. My question is: Should I create dummy variables for categories(1 to 7 which indicates product type) and stores(1 to 11)?

Comment: What are categories in here?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : **yes**.

Gradient boosting relies on **decision trees**. The leaves of your decision trees are built in a fashion to discriminate optimally your features. For numeric features, this means finding the **best separation value** to decline your dataset into two subsets. One contains observations with a value above or equal to this separation value, while the other presents values that are below this separation value.

It would not make any sense to have a leaf splitting your data on a criterion such as $Store >= 5$. However, it would make sense to have a separator such as $Store_5 = 1$ (vs $Store_5 = 0$). This is precisely why **dummy variables are created for categorical values in ensemble methods**, such as gradient boosting.

Comment: Creating dummy variables is only one way of handling categorical data. Another option may be impact (mean) encoding.

Comment: Also don't forget to add some features to your dataset as it will improve further and do check out the Yandex's CatBoost